# Creating a drop down list in asp.net mvc3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web

I am working on Simple Web Application using asp.net MVC4

I wonder to know how to create a drop down list in asp.net mvc4

In my application , I don't wanna use "ID_Sous_Type " but I wanna load a list from "Sous_Type" class

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf1C4.jpg

I wrote this code in my index method :

```
        var GenreLst = new List<string>();

        var GenreQry = from d in secdb.SousTypes
                       orderby d.ID_Sous_Type
                       select d.Nom_Sous_Type;
        GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());

        ViewBag.types = new SelectList(GenreLst); //Can't load this
```

In my View :

```
 @Html.DropDownList("types")
```

**UPDATE !**

I am working on a form to retrieve data and save it in my table 
I have two tables , Task and TaskType 
For Task , The creation page is being like that .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf1C4.jpg

For the last field "ID_Sous_Type" , I would like to load list (from other table TaskType) to give a good user interface where the user can choose an appropriate type in better way (giving ID_Sous_Type is not that understandable )
For that , I would like to load the names of (TaskType) in Dropdown List

In my index controller : 
I created .
 var GenreLst = new List();

//Here i got all the names from TaskType table

```
var GenreQry = from d in secdb.SousTypes
               orderby d.ID_Sous_Type
               select d.Nom_Sous_Type; 

GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
```

Then I added Ranges to easily get it 
but I couldn't "Bind" it in Dropdown list , I wonder to know HOW !!

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is here - could you please explain what you're expecting and what's actually happening?

Comment: PLease , Read the UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly your ViewBag.types is missing some vital information and that's why it's returning your list. It should be something like :

```
ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId","Name");
```

See this article on the official .net site it should help you understand dropdown lists better.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5